# How to get NSDecimalNumber from floatValue having same number of precision that the float value has?

Tags: objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I logged two `NSDecimalNumber`

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:2.675f]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:2.000f]);
```

I got the results in the console as

```
10:26 2013-05-16 10:23:20.807 SampleTest[1097:19d03] 2.674999952316284416
2013-05-16 10:23:22.484 SampleTest[1097:19d03] 2
```

My expected result is `2.0000`. It is fine to have any number of zero's after decimal But should have atleast one zero after the decimal point. It will be  hard for me to change the `NSDecimalNumber` datatype.

How can I acheive that. Can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any restrictions for using NSDecimalNumber?convert float into int and append 0's.

Comment: @Sunny : Yes, I need to convert float value to NSDecimalNumber Class, even if I append zero, NSDecimalNumber class is not giving me the precision(value after decimal point)

Answer (score 0):

As decimal number is a represented in *base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer*

Therefore 0s after decimal gets truncated. If you want explicitly then you need to use `float` or `double`.

```
NSDecimalNumber *deciA=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:2675 exponent:-3 isNegative:NO]; 
NSDecimalNumber *deciB=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:2000 exponent:-3 isNegative:NO];

    NSLog(@"deciA is %@",deciA);
    NSLog(@"deciB is %@",deciB);
```

**Output:**

> deciA is 2.675
>
> desiB is 2

You can do this way:

```
NSDecimalNumber *deciA=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:2.675f];
NSDecimalNumber *deciB=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:2.000f];
NSLog(@"deciA is %.3lf",[deciA doubleValue]);
NSLog(@"deciB is %.3lf",[deciB doubleValue]);
```

**Output:**

> deciA is 2.675
>
> desiB is 2.000

Comment: I can get the value like this .But I want NSDecimalNumber with precision

Comment: I have a DB , its dataformat is NSDecimalNumber.So I can't change the datatype

Comment: @Pavitra: NSDecimalNumber represents a decimal number, but it does not care about the *output format*. **"2" and "2.0000" is exactly the same for NSDecimalNumber**. The output of NSDecimalNumber with `%@` gives just some representation.  If you want to *print* the number with a given precision, you have to convert to double and use a `%f` output format (as Anoop said). Alternatively you can convert NSDecimalNumber to a string using NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: @MartinR : I want to pass this value to the server as decimal (2.0).

Comment: @Pavitra: your server will not be knowing about NSDecimal. That must be a Java based server that expects a float or decimal number.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : Server is not aware of the value.We have to sent it from client side